# C++ out-of-line definition

Tags: c++, struct, declaration, member, definition

I'm making a hash table and my class HashTable consists of the following struct and the following function in my header file:

```
class HashT
{
public:
  struct Node
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
  };

  Node** HashTArray;      

  void HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, struct Node** h2, unsigned int sz);

  HashT(const HashT& hm); (copy constructor that calls HashTCopy)

  unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;
 };
```

In my source file, I define the function as such and used it in my copy constructor:

```
void HashT::HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, Node** h2, unsigned int sz)
{
  ...
}  

HashT::HashT(const HashT& hm)
{
new_HashT = new Node* [hm.initialBucketCount]; 
HashTCopy(new_HashT, hm.HashTArray, hm.initialBucketCount)
}
```

When I try to compile this I get an error saying `out-of-line definition HashT::HashTCopy..."` and.... `note: type of 1st parameter of member declaration does not match definition. 'struct Node**' aka 'HashMap::Node** vs 'struct Node** aka HashMap::Node**'`. The compiler points to `struct`... 'void HashTCopy(**struct** Node** h1,....)`. I can't seem to figure out the problem. My declaration and definition match up so what is the issue here? Thanks

Comment: Show **all** your code, [because this works fine for me](http://ideone.com/MRwYvB)

Comment: will do. Added in the copy constructor that calls that function.

Comment: Why don't you define the implementation to use `HashT::Node` (instead of `struct Node`)?

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation, remove the `struct` before `Node`, i.e. change:

```
void HashT::HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, Node** h2, unsigned int sz)
```

to

```
void HashT::HashTCopy(Node** h1, Node** h2, unsigned int sz)
```

You don't need to write `struct` before variables of struct type in C++ (that's a C thing, and an outdated C thing at that). Your doing so here is confusing the compiler about what scope the name `Node` should appear in.

The `Node` struct is defined within the `HashT` class's namespace, so its full name is `HashT::Node`. Normally, types in a member function's argument list can be implicitly resolved within the class' namespace, without having to write `HashT::` in front of them. But the redundant `struct` here seems to be throwing it off, and making it think that you're talking about some *other* `Node` struct outside of the `HashT` class, which it can't find a definition for, and which doesn't match the class declaration.

I'm not sure what the standard says about this, so the compiler may actually be in error here, but I'd bet that removing the `struct` will fix it.

Comment: I removed `struct` from my declaration and my function signature and it gave me an error saying `unknown type name 'Node'

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
class HashT
{
public:
  struct Node
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
  };

  Node** HashTArray;      

  static void HashTCopy(Node** h1, Node** h2, unsigned int sz);

  HashT(const HashT& hm); (copy constructor that calls HashTCopy)

  unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;
 };
```

```
void HashT::HashTCopy(HashT::Node** h1, HashT::Node** h2, unsigned int sz)
{
  ...
}  

HashT::HashT(const HashT& hm)
{
new_HashT = new HashT::Node* [hm.initialBucketCount]; 
HashT::HashTCopy(new_HashT, hm.HashTArray, hm.initialBucketCount)
}
```

I think that the error is from the compiler not knowing exactly from where to get the `Node` structure, which is in the class `HashT`, so that by specifying the namespace (the class) in which the struct resides, will solve the provlem,

Comment: No, that’s unnecessary. Inside the function, the declaration of `Node` is in scope. In fact, OP’s code has multiple issues because it’s a fragment, but it does *not* contain the error in OP’s error message. (The question is also four years old …)

Answer (score -1):

```
HashT.h:

#ifndef HASHT_H
#define HASHT_H

#include <iostream>

class HashT
{
public:
  struct Node
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
  };

  Node** HashTArray;      

  void HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, struct Node** h2, unsigned int sz);

  HashT(const HashT& hm);

  unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;
 };

#endif

HashT.cpp:

#include "HashT.h"

void HashT::HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, Node** h2, unsigned int sz)
{
  //...
}  

HashT::HashT(const HashT& hm)
{
    Node** new_HashT = new Node* [hm.initialBucketCount]; 
    HashTCopy(new_HashT, hm.HashTArray, hm.initialBucketCount);
}
```

Comment: problem still exists :/. Idk why there's two different types. One being Node** and other being HashT::Node**

Comment: You need to declare new_HashT as "Node**"

Comment: I need new_HashT to be an array of pointers pointing to nodes.

Answer (score -1):

i had such problem in one of my QT project i resolved it by moving strut definition to top in header file

so try something like this by updating header filer to.

```
  struct Node
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    Node* next;
  };

class HashT
{
public:
  Node** HashTArray;      

  void HashTCopy(struct Node** h1, struct Node** h2, unsigned int sz);

  HashT(const HashT& hm); (copy constructor that calls HashTCopy)

  unsigned int initialBucketCount = 10;
 };
```